# How to change the font size of title of every dialog in an android application?

Tags: android, android-styles

I am looking for a solution to change the font size of the title of every Dialog in my application. I would like to change only the `styles.xml` without changing the code where the dialogs are created.

This is what I tried to do:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyOwnDialogTitle</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOwnDialogTitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">70sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>

</style>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: post the code what have you tried.

Comment: are you using custom layout for the dialog or using default dialog of android

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own style in style.xml with  textSize parameter and use this style in yours widgets. Look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create values folders like `values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi`. Then you can create values folder depending upon height or width and belongs to ldpi or mdpi i.e `values-w360dp-mdpi` or `values-h600dp-mdpi`. Then In these values folders create `styles.xml`. And set different font size in each styles.xml according to your requirement. Then android automatically picks layout depending upon screen size and values, style on depending height or width.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an attribute. I have done the same by:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomWindowTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWindowTitleTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```